# Move to the next element in foreach loop if entry already in the table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am basically running an upload file for users with their information on my application that is developed on codeigniter. It gets one row from the file and updates the table if the entry doesnt exist.

But I want to first check whether the entry is already in the database or not. In case it is it should move to the next element.

Following is my Model code.

```
function upload($file_name){
$file = './uploads/'.$file_name;


$this->load->library('excel');

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

$cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();

foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
    $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
    $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
    $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();


    if ($row == 1) {
        $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
    } else {
        $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
    }
}
//send the data in an array format
$data['header'] = $header;
$data['values'] = $arr_data;
foreach ($arr_data as $q){
$data = array(
    't_ref'=>$q['A'],
    't_name'=>ucwords($q['B']),
    't_cnic'=>$q['C'],
    't_dept'=>$q['D'],
    'status'=>$q['E']
    );
$this->db->select('t_cnic');
$this->db->where('t_cnic',$q['C']);
$this->db->from('tbl_users');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0){
break;
}else{
$this->db->insert('tbl_users',$data);
}
}
$msg = "Successfully Added";
return $msg;
}
```

(Break is not moving to the next element ofcourse)

How can i move to the next element rather than just stopping the loop whenever it finds an entry with the CNIC already existing in the table.

Comment: Normally "continue;" ?

Comment: Not sure how to change your query in codeignitor but you could use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE/IGNORE to either update the existing row with new values (even if they are the same as old values) or simply ignore the update and move to the next record.. This requires that your table has at least one unique index, or a 2 column index that when combined must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to break, or continue here, just tidy up the logic:

```
if ($query->num_rows()==0) {
    $this->db->insert('tbl_users',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `break` with [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

```
if($query->num_rows()>0) {
    continue;
} else {
```

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this

```
if($query->num_rows() === 0){
      $this->db->insert('tbl_users',$data);
      $msg = "Successfully Added";
   } else {
      $msg = "File Already exist";
    }

    return  $msg;
```